# Determine if the following system is a group or not.

Tags: group-theory

The set $T:=\lbrace(a,b)|a,b \in \mathbb{Z}\text{ and } b\ne 0\rbrace$ with operation $\ast$ given by $(a,b)\ast(c,d)=(ad+bc,bd)$.

I cannot decide if it even passes the axiom of closure seeing as $bd\ne 0$. Sorry if I am missing something simple, very new to group theory.

Comment: If $b,d \in \mathbb{Z} \setminus \{0\}$, then is their product 0?

Comment: What is the neutral element and do every element has an inverse?

Answer (score 1):

Neutral Element : $(a,b)*(c,d)=(ad+bc,bd)=(a,b)$
                  This implies $d=1$ and $c=0$ because of $b\ne 0$

Inverse Element : $(a,b)*(c,d)=(ad+bc,bd)=(0,1)$

If , for example $b=2$, we cannot fulfil $bd=1$. Therefore, we do not have an inverse, so we do not have a group.